# Existence of a physics-god

Tags: universe

In your opinion, what is the most cosmological or physics argument that may favor the existence of something like a god to produce a universe like ours and what is the most counter argument for that.

Please don't drag this discussion into theology.

Comment: "in your opinion[s]". Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Not really appropriate question for the physics stackexchange. The concept of a god as creator of the universe is not well defined, since first one would need to provide some physical mechanism by which such a god can "create" the space-time and matter in order to test such a god hypothesis.

Comment: By bringing up god you already dragged this discussion into theology.  This kind of nonsense simply doesn't belong here. -1 from me too.

Comment: It's always stricken me how much likeness there is between the deities of many cultures and the exquisitely low entropy state of the big bang (and the potential for creation of all kinds of things that follows from this). Indeed, I believe that part of the reason Einstein put his cosmological constant into his field equations was to try to stabilise the otherwise ever-dynamic state of contraction of expansion that seemed to follow from his field equations *because* it seemed to him that creation following from a single event was too eerily like monotheistic religions for his liking.

Comment: Think of cosmic eggs, monotheism: the big bang qualitatively resembles these - aside from the hissy fits of pique that the old testament Abrahamic god seemed to have on his bad hair days - we don't see them in experiment - or maybe we do in gamma ray bursts :)

Comment: "the most cosmological or physics argument that may favor the existence of something like a god" .. one simple and obvious answer that is often given is, of course, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_Universe.  Secondly the Fermi Paradox makes it knock-down blatantly obvious that we are living in a set-up universe.

Comment: @JoeBlow The anthropic principle kills the fine-tuned-universe argument

Comment: Jim, sigh, let's set aside that it is hugely strange to blankly claim *"the anthropic principle kills the fine-tuned-universe argument"* given the massive, ongoing, tremendous philosophical enquiry in to that issue. The question at hand is **which arguments** are most commonly used to, in a word, support religious-like positions.

Comment: Ask theological question.
Tell people not to talk about theology.
???
Profit.

Answer (score 7):

Counter Argument - A better part of the universe seems to be governed by certain laws (of Physics), which appears to preclude a Divine Creator. In fact, sometimes with such a precision that one expects that even those aspects that aren't well understood today, would be well understood some day, when issues with existing theories get resolved/ these theories get superseded.

Argument - Simply that the counter argument can't be rigorously proved. :P

It is simply a matter of belief, **either way**.

Comment: read it quickly, the Q will be closed soon enough. :)

Comment: no "counter arguments" are needed, the guy's just asking for a statement of "the cosmological/physics argument that may favor the existence of something like a God". (You do not have to agree or disagree, merely state which such observations are used.) Another one that's heard is "after a good 60 yrs of intense thought on the matter, we understand zilch about the quantum realm".  Like I say, the fine-tuned-universe observation and the Fermi Paradox are two obvious ones.

Comment: (Before anyone gets going, it's completely pointless to launch in to "refuting" those! The guy was just asking what are the typical such chains of thought. I thought it was a nice question!)

Comment: @JoeBlow - Notice the timings of the Q and A. My answer was a gut reaction, intended to be witty (OK, I failed!). You make a valid point. Maybe you could write a separate answer including those (if it is allowed for Q's on hold). I'll be happy to upvote :)

Comment: Hi NewNew - you know, it's not possible to place an Answer on a closed question. No biggie!

Comment: What are the arguments that can be used to confirm the necessity of a deity existence and what are the argument that conclude that there is no need for such a being. That was my question, but the stiffness of most people unfortunately caused alot of them to think that I was going to drag physics to theology.by the way , I am a hardcore atheist.

Comment: @Fadi - Putting a question on hold means that if it is not concordant with the site rules, it is giving you a chance of editing and improving. The way you formulate this question in the above comment looks fine to me, so maybe you can try editing that question and then give a custom flag to the moderators, saying that if it doesn't violate the rules, it may be reopened. I did that once on another SE site and it worked. So, it is worth a shot.

Comment: @Fadi - And, do not take the downvotes personally. As you say, they probably misunderstood your intended question, may be because it wasn't clear enough. I'm sure many of them will retract their downvotes if you edit and make it explicit what exactly you are asking. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @Fadi, your question was self-evidently a good question.  "Which features of cosmology are commonly used to support non-mechanistic views of existence?" It's hard not to get angry about it, but it's just a known feature of these sites that you occasionally get "irrational voting". Sometimes you "hit a nerve". For example the fine folks on this site, are probably "sick to death" of "ufo-conspiract-theory" -like questions about anti-gravity, perpetual motion etc!! So you can't blame different SO groups for some "relfex voting".

Comment: Note too that in fairness your question was a bit "quickly written" and folks often just vote-down "poorly written" questions.  Just FTR I edited your question a bit; feel free to change it back.